# Jpa @OnetoOne relationship with Java8

Tags: jpa, java-8, option-type

I can't use **java.util.Optional** (jdk8+) in JPA Entity.

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "authorId")
private Optional<Author> author;
```

and I get:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in:
com.mypackage.Album.author, referenced property unknown: java.util.Optional.authorId
```

Comment: two questions: why do you need an Optional field? Does it work without optional?

Comment: with _null_ author link I could test it with **Optional.isPresent**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use optional then implement `getter` method:

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "authorId")
private Author author;

public getAuthor(){
    return Optional.ofNullable(author);
}
```

Look at [*this*](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-java-1-8-optional-entity-attribute-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) to get details.